# I want to convert the row result of my query into 1 row

Tags: mysql

Here is my result rows:

```
COIL_ID    COIL                           SHEET_ID    SHEET
   3       P/CE TFS COIL 824mm X 0.18mm       0        Null
   0       Null                               12       P/CE TFS(c/l2s)866x822x0.18
```

The result i need is:

```
COIL_ID    COIL                           SHEET_ID    SHEET
   3       P/CE TFS COIL 824mm X 0.18mm       12       P/CE TFS(c/l2s)866x822x0.18
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: You need to show the query so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MAX` function *might* work here:

```sql
SELECT MAX(COIL_ID) AS COIL_ID, MAX(COIL) AS COIL, MAX(SHEET_ID) AS SHEET_ID,
       MAX(SHEET) AS SHEET
FROM yourTable;
```

I don't know the query which actually generated your current results, but the above would work assuming your starting point be the raw data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` function to get the latest record and group by ID.

```sql
SELECT
MAX(COIL_ID) AS COIL_ID,
MAX(COIL) AS COIL,
MAX(SHEET_ID) AS SHEET_ID,
MAX(SHEET) AS SHEET

FROM Table_Name

GROUP BY COIL_ID;
```